# Find an element from a list of elements in Twig (with a condition)

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to know if it is possible (in Twig) to find from a list of elements (say a like of book instances) one particular book satisfying a particular condition (for example has as previous volume a particular other book).
PS: in other words, is it possible to query a list in Twig ?
Thanks!

Comment: It is possible yes.. But your question is way to broad. What do you want to acomplish, what have u tried so far?

Comment: Twig extensions are your friend: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: do you have some example code of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your books and find the book you're looking for:

```
{# Look for a book with previous book = 9 #}
{% set previousBook = 9 %}
{# Define the books array #}
{% set books = {
    1: {'title': 'A', 'previous': [7, 8]},
    2: {'title': 'B', 'previous': [9, 10]}
} %}

{# By default there is no result #}
{% set foundBook = null%}

{# Loop through books #}
{% for bookId, book in books %}
    {# Apply the test #}
    {% if previousBook in book.previous %}
        {# The book has been found, store it #}
        {% set foundBook = book %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{# If a book has been found, display it #}
{% if foundBook is not null %}
    I found the "{{ foundBook.title }}" book which has previous book
        "{{ previousBook }}".
{% endif %}
```

But there is a high probability than you can do the same thing more easily by using this logic in the Controller.